# Keep localstorage moving from internal webview to crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, webview, local-storage, crosswalk-runtime

I've developed a cordova application which has been released on ~100 tablets. Now we want to use the power of crosswalk. Everything works except we lose localstorage information on update.

I've tried my best googling the answer but can't find any information how to migrate the information from internal webview to crosswalk webview.

So the question is: How do i keep localstorage when updating to crosswalk? (Or how do i access the localstorage of previous version?)

Cordova version of the released app: 3.6.3

On update:
Cordova: 5.1.1
Crosswalk: cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 (https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

Kind regards,

Jeroen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved it by using cordova-plugin-local-storage-retrieval with some changes. You can find our fork here: https://github.com/munisense/cordova-plugin-local-storage-retrieval

Comment: Out of interest, what does yours do different to DriftyCo's (and why did you have to change it)? :)

Comment: @keldar The version from DriftCo / Ionic seems to be a proof of concept. The output of their plugin is to the android console: https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-local-storage-retrieval/blob/master/src/android/LocalStoragePlugin.java#L127. So you dont have access to it in javascript. Our version does output previous localstorage to javascript so you can use it in your application to retrieve old values and save it in your new localstorage.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. I could get neither working :( so I think I'm going to have to live without it. For some reason, the injected JavaScript code returns "null" when ran.

Comment: @keldar Thats strange. Do you get a get 'null' on success function? I cant promise anything but if you create an issue on github explaining what you are trying to accomplish and what device + android version you are using I might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Jerome! I will create up a test-bed tonight to illustrate to you :). That's greatly appreciated.